# ¿Qué son volúmenes en «número de volúmenes de una sustancia»?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ciencia

> La graduación alcohólica o grado alcohólico volumétrico de una bebida alcohólica es la expresión en grados del **número de volúmenes de alcohol** (etanol) contenidos en **100 volúmenes del producto**, medidos a la temperatura de 20 ºC. — [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduaci%C3%B3n_alcoh%C3%B3lica)

Nunca he visto *volumen* usado así. Primeramente consulté el *[DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/volumen?m=form)* pero ninguna de las definiciones me parece relevante, ni tampoco 2 porque una sistema que se mide solo puede tener un volumen en cualquier momento. Por el contexto, supongo que «numero de volúmenes» quiere decir *valor numérico de la medida del volumen*, por lo tanto «número de volúmenes» significa *número de unidades volumétricas*.

¿He interpretado el texto correctamente? ¿Qué quieren decir las frases en negritas?

Comment: De acuerdo con _Leo_, con _gen-ℤ ready to perish_ y conmigo mismo, la expresión es, cuando menos, difícil de entender. Así que ya pone otra cosa en la Wikipedia.

Comment: @aerobiomat —pero hay que especificar que deben ser la misma unidad. O simplemente se puede dividir los volúmenes y dejar que las unidas se cancelan.

Comment: Hombre... El que se empeñe en usar dos unidades distintas de volumen en el numerador y el denominador se está buscando problemas. O es que ya lleva suficiente etanol encima.

Comment: @aerobiomat  de acuerdo +1 (también: ^unidades, no unidas). Dime, ¿qué te parece lo siguiente?: “Add six tablespoons of wine to a gallon of water and two cups of like juice for your detox diet.” Now calculate *that* %AV

Comment: Diluir vino en agua, además de ser pecado, es un problema que requiere dos pasos, así que voy a resolver un problema más sencillo:
"Add six tablespoons of pure ethanol to a gallon of water".
Como hay cucharadas y galones para todos los gustos, supongo que son imperiales.
No hay más que plantear el cociente y multiplicar por los factores de conversión a una unidad común:

6 tbsp / 1 gal = 6 tbsp / 1 gal * 0.0177582 L / 1 tbsp * 1 gal / 4.54609 L = 6 * 0.0177582 * 4.54609 = 0.023 (adimensional) = 2.3 %vol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que hablar de volúmenes permite establecer el grado de concentración de una sustancia en otra.

Si decimos que 100 volúmenes de vino contienen 10 volúmenes de alcohol, el vino tiene 10% de alcohol.

Si decimos que 100 volúmenes de whisky contienen 90 volúmenes de alcohol, el whisky tiene 90% de alcohol.

Por lo tanto, la graduación alcohólica será igual al número de volúmenes de alcohol presente en cada bebida (10 en el caso del vino, 90 en el caso del whisky).

Otra sustancia respecto de la cual se habla de "volúmenes" es el agua oxigenada, pero en este caso no se usa como porcentaje sino como múltiplo. Ver [esta explicación](https://www.vadequimica.com/blog/2015/09/agua-oxigenada-equivalencia-entre-volumenes-y-porcentaje/#:%7E:text=Agua%20oxigenada%20en%20vol%C3%BAmenes,970%20mililitros%20de%20agua%20destilada.):

> "Agua oxigenada 10 volúmenes" significa que 1 litro de la solución produce 10 litros de O2 en condiciones normales de presión y temperatura.

"Volúmenes" es entonces la cantidad de veces que X sustancia está contenida en otra, o la cantidad de veces que X sustancia produce otra.

Comment: Exactamente, el matemáticas es correcto, pero ¿qué es el volumen mismo en este contexto? ¿Hay una definición?

Comment: Al tratarse de líquidos, se miden en capacidad o volumen. Cada 100 litros o cada 100 decímetros cúbicos de vino contienen 10 litros o 10dm3 de alcohol.

Comment: Entonces… lo que conjeturé: una unidad volumétrica arbitraria, ¿no?

Comment: No lo veo como unidad volumétrica sino como un sinónimo algo lejano de "cantidades", sólo que al tratarse de líquidos no tiene sentido hablar de cantidades.

Comment: Ah, okay. Para mí, un metrologista de sala, el volumen es una cantidad, con dimensión de longitud elevado al cubo, escrito «dim *V* = L³», igual como cualquiera otra cantidad. Gracias por compartir tu punto de vista.

Comment: Quisiera aclarar que puse el check en esta respuesta porque provee otra instancia del uso

Answer (score 2):

La expresión es incorrecta y sospecho que es simplemente una mala traducción (automática) del artículo de Wikipedia en inglés. Lo correcto sería:

> ... la expresión en grados del número **de unidades** de volumen de
> alcohol (etanol) contenidos en 100 **unidades de** volumen del producto,
> medidos a la temperatura de 20 ºC

Aprovecho para sugerir que alguien corrija el artículo de Wikipedia.

Comment: ¿Incorrecta? Quizás la que tú indicas sea algo más precisa pero la expresión original es igual de correcta y comparándola con la inglesa no se trata de una traducción automática. Nótese que no aportas referencias de porqué es incorrecta, solo es tu opinión.

Comment: Unidades de volumen no es más preciso tampoco. Ejemplo: "Dígame 3 unidades de volumen, porque yo solo conozco el metro cúbico y el centímetro cúbico. Aunque estas 2 unidades de volumen son muy empleadas". Resulta que las unidades de volumen también pueden ser contadas.

Comment: @RubioRic Es cierto que no aporto referencias pero en la pregunta ya se incluye la referencia del DRAE en la cual se ve claramente que el uso de la palabra volúmenes no es correcta. No es cuestión de claridad (con un poco de imaginación se entiende el significado) sino de corrección gramatical.

Comment: @Javier Eso es exactamente lo que yo digo: las unidades de volumen pueden ser contadas, pero no los volúmenes. Volumen no es una palabra contable, unidad de volumen sí.

Comment: Precisamente al ser posible que las Unidades de Volumen sean contadas, la expresión número de unidades de volumen, se puede referir a las diferentes unidades de medir que existen.

Comment: Corregido el artículo en la Wikipedia.

Comment: Hay un montón de artículos y folletos, incluso algunos de autoridades oficiales, que usan el término "volúmenes" en referencia a la forma de medir los grados de alcohol.

Answer (score -1):

Según mi madrastra peruana:

> Es una expresión incorrecta. No tiene sentido. Hay que usar una unidad ahí.

También está de acuerdo que ninguna de las definiciones en el *DRAE* describen este uso de la palabra.

Comment: Al contrario de lo que opinan usted y su madrastra peruana, yo considero que la segunda acepción recogida en el DRAE es la que aplica a su contexto: "2. Magnitud física que expresa la extensión de un cuerpo en tres dimensiones, largo, ancho y alto, y cuya unidad en el sistema internacional es el metro cúbico". Como ha indicado Gustavson, no hay que usar una unidad específica porque sirve cualquiera, cada 100 centímetros cúbicos del producto, contienen X centímetros cúbicos de etanol. Puede sustituirse centímetros cúbicos por metros cúbicos o por litros y el enunciado se cumple igualmente.

Comment: @RubioRic la definición de [magnitud](https://dle.rae.es/magnitud) es "Propiedad física que puede ser medida". Por tanto, hablar de "90 volúmenes de alcohol" no tiene sentido, porque el alcohol no tiene "90 propiedades físicas que pueden ser medidas y expresan su extensión en tres dimensiones". Igual que no decimos "Hoy hay varias temperaturas más que ayer". Por tanto, creo que esta respuesta es válida, aunque quizá le falte citar fuentes fiables.

Comment: @wimi No estoy de acuerdo con tus apreciaciones. La frase original no se refiere a X volúmenes como X volúmenes distintos, con distintas medidas, sino X unidades del mismo volumen respecto a 100 unidades de ese mismo volumen. Tu enunciado respecto a las temperaturas no invalida las explicaciones de Gustavson que yo he repetido en mi comentario.